# How to make ng-click function wait for jQuery script to finish before executing?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, timeout, wait

I need to clear a `ul` list of current items before making a REST call to Flickr's API which would then fill it again with 20 items. At the moment these are being run simultaneously which causes the list to remain with 0 items despite grabbing 20 new ones.

The REST call is currently sitting inside one of my services. From my searches I've found two possible solutions, `$timeout` and `$viewContentLoaded`, or possibly combining them into one solution. However, in my case I can't figure out how I would implement this for it to work properly.

Script to execute before anything else:

**JQuery Code:**

```
$('#fav-tags-list').on('click', 'li', function() {

    $('#images-list').children('li').remove();
    $('#fav-tags-list li').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

The function that gets called by the `ng-click` (getImages):

```
flickrApp.service('shared', function() {
    var imageGroup = [];

    return {
        getImages: function(tag) {

            if (tag === false) {
                var options = {
                    format: 'json',
                    tagmode: 'ANY'
                }
            }
            else {
                var options = {
                    format: 'json',
                    tags: tag,
                    tagmode: 'ANY'
                }
            }

            $.getJSON('https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?', options, function(data) {

                $.each(data.items, function(i, image) {

                    imageGroup.push(data.items[i]);
                });
            });

            return imageGroup;
        }
    };
});
```

Markup for the `ng-click` (stripped of attributes):

```
<ul id="fav-tags-list">
    <li ng-repeat="tag in tagsList" ng-bind="tag"
        ng-click="shared.getImages(tag)"></li>
</ul>
```

**EDIT:** As requested here's how I consumed the service:

```
flickrApp.controller('flickrCtrl', ['$scope', '$firebase', 'shared', function($scope, $firebase, shared) {

    $scope.shared = shared;

    //Get a set of images on pageload
    $scope.imageGroup = shared.getImages(false);

}]);
```

I'm not even sure this is what I'm looking for here, so I'd appreciate some guidance.

Comment: don't use jquery inside angular code..use `$http.get` or `$resource`..that will create a bottle neck for digest cycle to run

Comment: Totally forgot about $http.get.. will change and update question.

Comment: Thats wrong code inside service..could you please add you controller code..i want to see how you are consuming service..seems like service is not returning any promise..

Comment: @pankajparkar I've cut out some functions from my return in the service, but overall it works as intended. When using $http.get I can't get access to the API, it just throws access violation errors all over the place that's why I had to use $.getJSON instead to achieve what I wanted.

Comment: then you may need to run angular $digest cycle by your own.to update scope variable using $scope.$apply()

Comment: I doubt by your code, `$scope.imageGroup` data is updating?

Comment: I have to click things twice for it to upgrade, so yes I need to use apply in some sense. Just can't figure out where and how since I'm using a service to update the imageGroup. Would you be able to write an example based on my situation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70486/discussion-between-pankajparkar-and-chrillewoodz).

Answer (score 1):

if you're trying to make a delay when a function is called your could do something like this:

```
<html>
<button ng-click="do()"></button>
</html>

<script>

    $scope.do = function() {
        $timeout( function(){
             //your code here
        },10000, true );
    }
<script>
```

or a more efficient way to do the same thing is to just wrap it with timeout()